# writing files python i think i have issue with else:count

Tags: python, file-writing

Write a function named "internet_histogram" that takes no parameters and does not return a value. There will be a file named "survey.csv" in the testing environment containing survey results as described above (the file has a header line which much be addressed by your code). Write a new file named "histogram.csv" containing 2 columns representing "internet_use,frequency" and no header line that will contain a histogram of the results of responders ages 28 to 29 including the endpoint ages. Your file will have exactly 6 lines with internet_use values of 1-5 corresponding to the intfreq results and 6 for responders who answered 2 to eminuse. Read the survey results file and track how many responders in this age range answered with each of these 6 options and write these counts to your "histogram.csv" file in order of internet_use starting with 1.
Example histogram.csv:
1,5
2,7
3,0
4,1
5,2
6,4

my code:

```
import csv
def internet_histogram():
    count_6 = 0
    count_5 = 0
    count_4 = 0
    count_3 = 0
    count_2 = 0
    count_1 = 0
    with open("survey.csv",'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open("histogram.csv", 'w') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                if int(line[3]) >= 28 and int(line[3]) <= 29:
                    if line[2] != '':
                        if int(line[2]) == 1:
                            count_1 += 1
                        if int(line[2]) == 2:
                            count_2 += 1
                        if int(line[2]) == 3:
                            count_3 += 1
                        if int(line[2]) == 4:
                            count_4 += 1
                        if int(line[2]) == 5:
                            count_5 += 1
            else:
                count_6 = count_6 + 1
                arr = [[1, count_1], [2, count_2], [3, count_3], [4, count_4], [5, count_5], [6, count_6]]
                for i in arr:
                    writer.writerow(i)
```

output:
wrote: "1,26
2,29
3,2
4,3
5,1
6,1
"
expected: "1,26
2,29
3,2
4,3
5,1
6,2
"

i think its an issue with the else statement but I'm not quite sure, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your `else` is missing an indentation. So it's referring to the `for` instead of the `if`.

Comment: i tried that earlier, it just turned into a loop with over a 1000 values looping over and over

Comment: It's hard to judge something I don't see, but did you un-indent the second `for` loop when you tried that?

Comment: Also, your `else` would only refer to the last `if`. Maybe use `elif`s.

Comment: yeah i tried multiple different indenting methods for the else statement

Answer (score 0):

The way it's written now you'll always get a count of `1` for the `6` column.
You should indent the `else` so as to count this case along with the others, but using `else` would only refer to the last `if`, so it would count all the cases for which `int(line[2]) != 5`, which probably isn't what you're trying to do.
For best python zen explicitness, I would use the following instead of `else`:

```
if int(line[2]) not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    count_6 += 1
```

Does that work for you?
Good luck!

Comment: wrote: ""
expected: "1,26
2,29
3,2
4,3
5,1
6,2
"

Comment: And you got a 1 at the end instead of 2? Well that's because it's outside the loop so it has no way of being anything other than 1.

Comment: Yeah i know what you're talking about, gonna try to mess around with the else statement and see if I can go from there. I appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. Maybe add the data you're working with. Hard to help you debug this way.
2. What did my solution give?

Answer (score 0):

Not too well-versed in Python yet myself, but I fixed your program by shifting some indentation here, along with a few other minor changes:

```
import csv
def internet_histogram():
    count_6 = 0
    count_5 = 0
    count_4 = 0
    count_3 = 0
    count_2 = 0
    count_1 = 0
    with open("survey.csv",'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open("histogram.csv", 'w') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                if int(line[3]) >= 28 and int(line[3]) <= 29:
                    if line[2] != '':
                        if int(line[2]) == 1:
                            count_1 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 2:
                            count_2 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 3:
                            count_3 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 4:
                            count_4 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 5:
                            count_5 += 1
                    else:
                        count_6 = count_6 + 1
                    arr = [[1, count_1], [2, count_2], [3, count_3], [4, count_4], [5, count_5], [6, count_6]]
            for i in arr:
                writer.writerow(i)
```